# What would be the roots of the derivative of this polynomial

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I got this $$ f=a(x-1)(x-2)...(x-101) $$ knowing a and that $1 ,2 \ldots ,101$ are it's roots ... I need the roots of $f'$ , how should I do it ? More specifc how can I derivate a polynomial like that, is there a formula or something ?

Comment: Have you tried computing $f'$ ?

Comment: i am kind new , how can i do that ?

Comment: yeah mb , i know the value of a but only 1 , 2 ,3 ... are it's roots

Comment: How to compute the derivative? Well, you see that $f$ is a product of several simpler terms. You can use the chain rule.

Comment: Apply the product rule over and over again, like the [triple product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66683/derivative-of-product-of-three-functions-product-rule). Start from $f'(x) = a\left((x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-100))' (x-101))+ ((x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-100)) \cdot (x-101)' \right) $.

Comment: dosen't realy leads to something usefull ... how can i extract the roots of that

Comment: @MattiP: chain rule ? You probably mean product rule.

Comment: From one of your comments to other posts, it appears you may only want the sum of the roots of the derivative.  If so, **you need to first correct your question.** It is best to ask exactly what you want for others to help, you can always share what you have done in case that’s something others can complete.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the derivative thus.

Taking logs, we get $$\log f=\log a+\sum_{i=1}^{101}{\log(x-i)},$$ so that differentiating gives $$f'=f\sum_{i=1}^{101}{\frac{1}{x-i}}.$$

Comment: Actually you can get exactly the same result without the log-trick, by derivating directly the product. Yet it doesn't yield the roots of the derivative in an obvious way.

Comment: @Evargalo: this way to evaluate the derivative is much more efficient. It yields a formula with a product of 101 factors by the sum of 101 terms, vs. the sum of 101 terms each made of 100 factors, i.e. expression length $O(n)$ vs. $O(n^2)$. I would recommend it to evaluate the derivative, except in a close neighborhood of a root of $f$. (To find the roots of $f'$, you can ignore the factor $f$.)

Comment: and in the end ... how am i supposed to do the sum of the roots ? the answer says it is 5100 but i realy don't understand how you get there on paper

Comment: @VlAdTbK Do you need the roots or the sum of the roots? You talked about the derivative and its roots only in OP.

Comment: The sum of the roots would be much easier. I expect it is exactly $5100$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : but both formulas (factorised or expended) can be reached by either method since you can pass easily from one to the other.

Comment: @Evargalo: you miss the point. The amount of work is much larger by the derivative-of-product formula. By a factor 50.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed I had missed the point of too much complexity because I had reached the result in three lines... A simple recurrence (as example, it is not that the recurrence is needed) reduces the 100 steps to only 2, so the amount of work is not that overwhelming !

Comment: @Evargalo: computationally, $O(n^2)$ vs. $O(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

From one of your comments to other posts, it appears you may only want the sum of the roots of the derivative.  If so, *you need to first correct your question.* Assuming this is the case, all you need is Vieta’s rule and the first two terms of $f’$.
i.e.
$f = a\,x^{101}-a(1+2+3+\cdots+101)\,x^{100}+\cdots$
$\implies f’ = 101a\,x^{100} + 100a \cdot(\frac12\cdot101\cdot 102)\, x^{99}+\cdots$
$\implies $ sum of roots $\displaystyle= \frac{100a\cdot\frac12\cdot101\cdot 102}{101a}=5100$

Comment: yeah that's what i needed , but how did you done it ? I stil don't rly understand how you got to it

Comment: Well, edit the question, then tell me which step i need to explain.

Comment: i found the answer , thank you though

Answer (score -1):

As it was mentioned in previous comments, there will be a root of $f'$ on each interval $]k,k+1[, \quad k=1, \cdots , 100$. If you want a numerical approximation you can simply use Newton's method on each of these intervals , taking for instance as initial approximation $x^{(0)}_k = k + \frac{1}{2}$. if you use Mathematica you can get all the solution at once by issuing the commands

$$f[x\_]:=Product[x-i,\{i,1,101\}]$$
$$NSolve[f'[x]==0,x, WorkingPrecision \to 20]$$

$$
\{\{x\to 1.1808291122087612164\},\{x\to 2.2100807699421299589\},\{x\to 3.2293475049454603245\},\{x\to
   4.2443987137725789046\},\{x\to 5.2570499827658189815\},\{x\to 6.2681262040946746698\},\{x\to
   7.2780782056966400068\},\{x\to 8.2871819479287411490\},\{x\to 9.2956198975910239024\},\{x\to
   10.303519661327208567\},\{x\to 11.310974371094841091\},\{x\to 12.318054322065932283\},\{x\to
   13.324814035448533182\},\{x\to 14.331296759703496401\},\{x\to 15.337537456561865561\},\{x\to
   16.343564849324371068\},\{x\to 17.349402868386108329\},\{x\to 18.355071696567098598\},\{x\to
   19.360588541240691774\},\{x\to 20.365968215372014879\},\{x\to 21.371223582016873610\},\{x\to
   22.376365899396812647\},\{x\to 23.381405092345185275\},\{x\to 24.386349968394921691\},\{x\to
   25.391208391672422480\},\{x\to 26.395987424230801866\},\{x\to 27.400693441971712575\},\{x\to
   28.405332230530290552\},\{x\to 29.409909065211691911\},\{x\to 30.414428778123500341\},\{x\to
   31.418895814946718692\},\{x\to 32.423314283260973905\},\{x\to 33.427687993939492301\},\{x\to
   34.432020496822844042\},\{x\to 35.436315111643480438\},\{x\to 36.440574954988405275\},\{x\to
   37.444802963942305840\},\{x\to 38.449001916938810424\},\{x\to 39.453174452256307664\},\{x\to
   40.457323084521758049\},\{x\to 41.461450219527214269\},\{x\to 42.465558167616346035\},\{x\to
   43.469649155859836112\},\{x\to 44.473725339207302760\},\{x\to 45.477788810778033494\},\{x\to
   46.481841611432215602\},\{x\to 47.485885738747685453\},\{x\to 48.489923155513841196\},\{x\to
   49.493955797843767137\},\{x\to 50.497985582997415037\},\{x\to 51.502014417002584963\},\{x\to
   52.506044202156232863\},\{x\to 53.510076844486158804\},\{x\to 54.514114261252314547\},\{x\to
   55.518158388567784398\},\{x\to 56.522211189221966506\},\{x\to 57.526274660792697240\},\{x\to
   58.530350844140163888\},\{x\to 59.534441832383653965\},\{x\to 60.538549780472785731\},\{x\to
   61.542676915478241951\},\{x\to 62.546825547743692336\},\{x\to 63.550998083061189576\},\{x\to
   64.555197036057694160\},\{x\to 65.559425045011594725\},\{x\to 66.563684888356519562\},\{x\to
   67.567979503177155958\},\{x\to 68.572312006060507699\},\{x\to 69.576685716739026095\},\{x\to
   70.581104185053281308\},\{x\to 71.585571221876499659\},\{x\to 72.590090934788308089\},\{x\to
   73.594667769469709448\},\{x\to 74.599306558028287425\},\{x\to 75.604012575769198134\},\{x\to
   76.608791608327577520\},\{x\to 77.613650031605078309\},\{x\to 78.618594907654814725\},\{x\to
   79.623634100603187353\},\{x\to 80.628776417983126390\},\{x\to 81.634031784627985121\},\{x\to
   82.639411458759308226\},\{x\to 83.644928303432901402\},\{x\to 84.650597131613891671\},\{x\to
   85.656435150675628932\},\{x\to 86.662462543438134439\},\{x\to 87.668703240296503599\},\{x\to
   88.675185964551466818\},\{x\to 89.681945677934067717\},\{x\to 90.689025628905158909\},\{x\to
   91.696480338672791433\},\{x\to 92.704380102408976098\},\{x\to 93.712818052071258851\},\{x\to
   94.721921794303359993\},\{x\to 95.731873795905325330\},\{x\to 96.742950017234181018\},\{x\to
   97.755601286227421095\},\{x\to 98.770652495054539676\},\{x\to 99.789919230057870041\},\{x\to
   100.81917088779123878\}\}
$$

Comment: Any thoughts on why the downvote?

Answer (score -2):

**Original Answer**

To answer the question in the title, I've asked Mathematica:

> NSolve[D[f[x, 101], x] == 0, x]

where

$$f_n(x)=\prod \limits_{k=1}^n (x-k)$$

<strike>Turns out the result $x_1=x_2=...=x_{100}=51$. I'm still thinking about how you can do this with some brain power or pen and pencil, but I'm sure there are brighter minds than me around here.</strike>

### **Update**

After fixing the Mathematica code, these are the (numerically found) roots:

```
 >1.18083  
 >2.21008  
 >3.22935  
 >4.2444  
 >5.25705  
 >6.26813  
 >7.27808  
 >8.28718  
 >9.29562  
 >10.3035  
 >11.311  
 >12.3181  
 >13.3248  
 >14.3313  
 >15.3375  
 >16.3436  
 >17.3494  
 >18.3551  
 >19.3606  
 >20.366  
 >21.3712  
 >22.3764  
 >23.3814  
 >24.3863  
 >25.3912  
 >26.396  
 >27.4007  
 >28.4053  
 >29.4099  
 >30.4144  
 >31.4189  
 >32.4233  
 >33.4277  
 >34.432  
 >35.4363  
 >36.4406  
 >37.4448  
 >38.449  
 >39.4532  
 >40.4573  
 >41.4615  
 >42.4656  
 >43.4696  
 >44.4737  
 >45.4778  
 >46.4818  
 >47.4859  
 >48.4899  
 >49.494  
 >50.498  
 >51.502  
 >52.506  
 >53.5101  
 >54.5141  
 >55.5182  
 >56.5222  
 >57.5263  
 >58.5304  
 >59.5344  
 >60.5385  
 >61.5427  
 >62.5468  
 >63.551  
 >64.5552  
 >65.5594  
 >66.5637  
 >67.568  
 >68.5723  
 >69.5767  
 >70.5811  
 >71.5856  
 >72.5901  
 >73.5947  
 >74.5993  
 >75.604  
 >76.6088  
 >77.6137  
 >78.6186  
 >79.6236  
 >80.6288  
 >81.634  
 >82.6394  
 >83.6449  
 >84.6506  
 >85.6564  
 >86.6625  
 >87.6687  
 >88.6752  
 >89.6819  
 >90.689  
 >91.6965  
 >92.7044  
 >93.7128  
 >94.7219  
 >95.7319  
 >96.743  
 >97.7556  
 >98.7707  
 >99.7899  
 >100.819
```

Comment: so the roots are the same as from the first polynomial , except the last one ? I don't realy undesrstand tbh

Comment: No, you have 100 roots and they are all the same. $x_1=51, x_2=51, ... x_{100}=51$

Comment: i guess it works this way too , i knew the sum of them was 5100 but i was thinking it was from gauss sum , haveing the roots from 1 to 100

Comment: Are you sure of that ?

Comment: This result is plain wrong, there is no root of multiplicity $100$. The derivative must have a root in every $[k,k+1]$ interval. The OP is wrong to accept blindly.

Comment: I was confused about this as well. I might as well ask on mathematica.stackexchange how Mathematica figured this one out.

Comment: Could you provide the Mathematica syntax you used for the defintion of *f[x,n]* ?

Comment: See here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202166/nsolve-gives-weird-result-for-n-101-with-nsolve-fracddx-prod-limits-k

Comment: @infinitezero It is a matter of numerical precision. If you add the option WorkingPrecision->20 to your NSolve command you will get the correct answer. This is why we can't leave everything to machines!

Comment: Yes, thank you. I blindly thought, though it seemed weird, I must agree, that it was in the spirit of the question that for $n=101$ this somehow produces a nice result.