# Second derivative of product series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, products

I am trying to find the second derivative of a product series 
$\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x) $

I found an answer from Arturo Magidin in [First derivative product series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50932/687213), which is pretty convincing and easy to understand.

I tried to follow the same steps to get the second derivative and this is what I got:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{''}(x) \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n} f_j(x)$ + $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{'}(x) \sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n} f_j^{'}(x) \prod_{k=1, k\neq j}^{n} f_k(x)$

My question is, is my derivation correct? If not, where am I making a mistake? And is there any way to simplify this more?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Arturo is a male name.

Comment: Look at yoyo's comment on the linked question, which gives a compact formula for the $n$th derivative.

Comment: Tangential: If you're unsure as to the person's title, it's probably best not to use "Mr/Ms" and simply refer to the person by name.

Comment: Heh; “Arturo” is most definitely a male name; it’s just Spanish or “Arthur”.

Comment: Yes, you can simplify it. If you think about each of the summands after the first derivative, taking the derivative of that will give you a sum in which one term has a second derivative, and all other terms have two first derivatives. So your first summand takes care of all the second derivatives that occur. The second summand can be simplified because you will get *two* summands for every pair of first derivatives, so you can rewrite the second summand as $2\left(\sum_{1\leq i\lt j\leq n}f_i’(x)f_j’(x)\prod_{k=1,k\neq i,k\neq j}^n f_k(x)\right)$.

Comment: However, your formula is almost but not quite right: your final $k$ must also be different from $i$, not just from $j$.