# Derivative of differential equation

Tags: calculus

The third degree seems to be incorrect when I use the derivative formula. Could someone guide me
$$\begin{align}
&y'=-2xy^2\\
&y''=-2[y^2+xyy']\\
&y'''=-2[2yy'+yy'+(xy')^2+xyy'']\\
&y''''=?
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the derivative of a product of $n$ functions is the sum of $n$ products where we differentiate just one factor at the time (see also [The derivative of a product of more than two functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50927/the-derivative-of-a-product-of-more-than-two-functions)?). For example for $3$ functions,
$$(fgh)'=f'gh+fg'h+fgh'.$$
Therefore, it should be
$$y''=-2[y^2+\color{blue}{2}xyy']$$
$$y'''=-2[2yy'+\color{blue}{2}yy'+\color{blue}{2x(y')^2}+\color{blue}{2}xyy''].$$
What is the fourth-derivative $y''''$?