# Leibniz theorem for successive differentiation

Tags: calculus, differential

I want to study Leibniz's theorem of successive differentiation and unfortunately, I found no books online to study and have some rigorous practice on the topic. I have some local books but they are extremely vague and not stated with clarity. Can anyone recommend me a book where it contains the theory with proper clarity and in-depth exercises?

Comment: Could you give an example? Which theorem do you mean? (And Leibniz is written without a 't'.) Do you mean the chain rule?

Comment: Yes the nth derivative of two functions multiplied together (like in :(uv)_n)

Comment: See this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50927/305862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapter 9, Section 3 of the 3rd edition of Boas's *Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences* gives some explicit examples of the use of Leibniz's rule for differentiating products, and assigns a few problems on it.

Section 1.4 of the 7th edition of Arfken, Weber, and Harris's *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* has the reader prove as an exercise Leibniz's rule for the repeated differentiation of a product, and then uses it in a few places throughout the text. You  might find some intuition there.

The reference on the relevant Wikipedia page is for Olver's  *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations*, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main calculation:
\begin{align*}
(f\cdot g)'(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{1}{h}\left(f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))+(f(x+h)-f(x))g(x)\right)\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}g(x)\\
&=\left(\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h\right)\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}+\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)g(x)\\
&=f(x)\cdot g'(x)+f'(x)\cdot g(x)
\end{align*}